# "Lorem ipsum" web service data in JSON?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp, lorem-ipsum

Are there any sample web services served via JSON out there? I would like to consume some for testing and learning. I also would not mind downloading JSON files offline with images and stuff. Maybe there is even live public data that I can consume for learning instead. It would save so much time starting projects or prototypes. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're just looking for random data structures in JSON form? How does that make any sense? JSON is not self-describing (well not without some set of conventions beyond plain JSON).

Comment: Why not just use a real api like https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api then you'd also learn something useful :)

Comment: Check this out: http://json-generator.appspot.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia is an easy example of this.

Here's a pretty printed version:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=info&format=jsonfm&callback=foo

And here's it in jsonp:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=info&format=json&callback=foo